# Pop the first inserted key-value pair in a dictionary [Python 3.7+]

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary in `python 3.9`:

```py
dictionary = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 3,
    'c': 4
}
```

If I use `dictionary.popitem()`, it pops and returns `('c', 4)`. 
Is there any way to retrieve `('a', 2)`, i.e the first item, in `O(1)` time?

Comment: Although dictionaries retain insertion order they're still not _semantically_ ordered, there's no method for the "first" thing. There is an ordered mapping with such methods: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a builtin way to achieve this, but you can write a short function:

```
def popfirst(d):
    k = next(iter(d))    # get the first key
    return (k, d.pop(k)) # pop based on the key

popfirst(dictionary)
```

output: `('a', 2)`